# TabHost with black background in some devices

Tags: android, tabs

Hi have an `TabHost` that is set up like this:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.datatab, parent, false);
TabHost tabs = (TabHost) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
TextView microTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dataTabsTitle);
microTitle.setTypeface(fontBold);

tabs.setup();
TabSpec tab1 = tabs.newTabSpec("TabOne");
TabSpec tab2 = tabs.newTabSpec("TabTwo");
TabSpec tab3 = tabs.newTabSpec("TabThree");
tab1.setContent(this);
tab2.setContent(this);
tab3.setContent(this);
tab1.setIndicator(mContext.getString(R.string.dataOneTitle));
tab2.setIndicator(mContext.getString(R.string.dataTwoTitle));
tab3.setIndicator(mContext.getString(R.string.dataThreeTitle));
tabs.addTab(tab1);
tabs.addTab(tab2);
tabs.addTab(tab3);
tabs.addTab(tab4);
tabs.setup();
tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orangetabs_tab_indicator_holo);

    TextView tv = (TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorone));
    tv.setTypeface(fontBold);
}
```

The drawable was generated using [android holo colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and is like this:

```
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/orangetabs_tab_unselected_focused_holo"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/orangetabs_tab_selected_focused_holo"/>

<!-- Pressed --><!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orangetabs_tab_unselected_pressed_holo"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orangetabs_tab_selected_pressed_holo"/>

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orangetabs_tab_unselected_pressed_holo"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orangetabs_tab_selected_pressed_holo"/>
```

Although I'm setting the background color to each view with `v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));`, on some devices, the background is showing as black.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments I've tried to set the backgroud color (`tabs.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white))‌​;`) but with no success
It still shows like this:

[image]

Comment: `TabHost` is deprecated long ago, You need to use either `toolbar` or `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: Thanks. My app is old and now I've stopped the development and providing only some bug fixes. This is why I still need to use it.

Comment: set the background color to tabhost tabs.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white)); and can you show me the layout @Favolas

Comment: @hareesh145 Thanks but that did not solve. Please see my updated question

Comment: you have taken the direct child to the tabhost is linearlayout.so get that id and set the background to that linearlayout @Favolas

Comment: @Favolas I had same experience before but only below 4.1 in android device
If you determined setBackgroundColor.android.color.TRANSPARENT then it may give background black color in some devices so that try to make which color you want instead TRANSPARENT

Comment: No. In all my project I never set the color as transparent :(